# Application not work with js.coffee

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just started a new project through console, and created new controller "index" 
also through console which added file:

```
create      app/assets/javascripts/index.js.coffee
```

Now if I try to open index/index I see the error:
ExecJS::RuntimeError in Index#index

I found some similar posts on stackoverflow, but the solutions in this threads was made by me and there is no solve: gem "therubyracer" and nodejs is installed

i dont know what to do, if I delete file index.js.coffee - all works fine. 
Rails 3.2.8
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]

Answer (score 0):

You are missing node.js

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: did you restart the server after installing node?

Comment: yes of course, node was installed many weeks ago, server was restarted    additionally today

Comment: are you using rvm? try running rvm-requirements, install those and then reinstall ruby and rails.